# Determine the user is premium - Qonversion API

Tags: android, kotlin, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing, subscription

With the Qonversion API, I am adding a feature for users to purchase subscriptions. When the user comes back after the purchased subscription, I want to check the subscription status, but I get a "null" value from checkEntitlements as a return. At the same time, although the purchase is positive in the purchase function, it does not enter onSuccess at all. How can I check the user's subscription status? (When I try to subscribe again after the purchase is made, google says I am already subscribed, so the subscription process is successful.)

Fragment:

```
class PurchaseFragment : Fragment() {
    private var _binding: FragmentPurchaseBinding? = null
    private val binding get() = _binding!!

    private var product: QProduct? = null
```

Displaying product:

```
 private fun displayProducts() {
            Qonversion.shared.offerings(object : QonversionOfferingsCallback {
                override fun onSuccess(offerings: QOfferings) {
                    val mainOffering = offerings.main
                    if (mainOffering != null && mainOffering.products.isNotEmpty()) {   
                        binding.monthlyPrice.text = mainOffering.products[0].prettyPrice
                        product = mainOffering.products[0]
                    }
                }
    
                override fun onError(error: QonversionError) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Error: $error")
                }
            })
        }
```

Making purchase:

```
 private fun makePurchase(product: QProduct) {
            Qonversion.shared.purchase(
                requireActivity(),
                product,
                callback = object : QonversionEntitlementsCallback {
                    override fun onSuccess(entitlements: Map<String, QEntitlement>) {
                        val premiumEntitlement = entitlements["premium_permisson"]
                        if (premiumEntitlement != null && premiumEntitlement.isActive) {
                            Log.d(TAG, "Entitlements: $premiumEntitlement")
                        } else {
                            Log.d(TAG, "Entitlements else: $premiumEntitlement")
                        }
                    }
    
                    override fun onError(error: QonversionError) {
                        // Handle error here
                        if (error.code === QonversionErrorCode.CanceledPurchase) {
                            Log.d(TAG, "Canceled")
                        }
                    }
                })
        }
```

Check status of user:

```
private fun isItPremiumUser() {
    Qonversion.shared.checkEntitlements(object : QonversionEntitlementsCallback {
        override fun onSuccess(entitlements: Map<String, QEntitlement>) {
            val premiumEntitlement = entitlements["premium_permisson"]

            Log.d(TAG, "isItPremiumUser $premiumEntitlement") // it returns null
            if (premiumEntitlement != null && premiumEntitlement.isActive) {
                Log.d(TAG, "isItPremiumUser Entitlements: $premiumEntitlement")
                // handle active entitlement here

                // also you can check renew state if needed
                // for example to check if user has canceled subscription and offer him a discount
                when (premiumEntitlement.renewState) {
                    QEntitlementRenewState.NonRenewable -> {
                        Log.d(TAG, "NonRenewable Entitlements: $premiumEntitlement")
                        // NonRenewable is the state of a consumable or non-consumable in-app purchase
                    }
                    QEntitlementRenewState.WillRenew -> {
                        Log.d(TAG, "WillRenew Entitlements: $premiumEntitlement")
                        // WillRenew is the state of an auto-renewable subscription
                    }
                    QEntitlementRenewState.BillingIssue -> {
                        Log.d(TAG, "BillingIssue Entitlements: $premiumEntitlement")
                        // Prompt the user to update the payment method.
                    }
                    QEntitlementRenewState.Canceled -> {
                        Log.d(TAG, "Canceled Entitlements: $premiumEntitlement")
                        // The user has turned off auto-renewal for the subscription, but the subscription has not expired yet.
                        // Prompt the user to resubscribe with a special offer.
                    }
                    else -> {
                        Log.d(TAG, "else Entitlements: $premiumEntitlement")
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        override fun onError(error: QonversionError) {
            // handle error here
           Log.d(TAG, "onError: $error")
        }
    })
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If `onSuccess` is not called on your `purchase` call, check the `onError` method. It looks like something went wrong while handling your purchase on the Qonversion side and the error information, provided to the corresponding callback would explain the reason. Also, the device logs would be helpful - Qonversion SDK logs useful information while handling purchases.

If the purchase on the Google side was successful, it might be a problem with your Qonversion Product Center configuration or Google Play configuration in Qonversion Settings.

You can read more about it in the official documentation [here](https://documentation.qonversion.io/docs/quickstart#2-create-a-project-and-register-your-app) and [here](https://documentation.qonversion.io/docs/subscription-management-mode). If you'll face any further issues, for quicker help consider contacting Qonversion support via the website widget.